# passing angular directive to cellTooltip of ui grid

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-grid

how to pass angular directive in cellToolTip of ui grid?. I tried following but didn't work

```
var columnDef = [
        {
            field: 'name',
            name: 'name',
            displayName: 'Name'
        },
        {
            field: 'xyz',
            name: 'xyz',
            displayName: 'xyz t/y',
            cellTooltip: function (row, col) {
                return $sce.trustAsHtml('<div><x-y name=row.entity.name></x-y></div>')
            }
        }]
```

Comment: Well I don't see how your arg is getting passed into the directive.  You have it there but it's a string value, you may need to convert to an expression ({{ row.entity.name }}.  Your directive may not be compiling as well.  A bit tricky without seeing more code

Comment: hi, yes thats correct, the directive is not compiling, my main concern is to get the directive working.